# Hide Facebook customer chat plugin if user is not logged it

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm trying to hide the Facebook customer chat plugin when the user is not logged in into Facebook.

I've looked at the API here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/

But this method doesn't seem to exist. However I can change the message If the user is not logged in.

Can I somehow listen to that and then hide it?

Comment: At most you could use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/ to check.

Comment: Hi @misorude Thanks for the link. I tried adding `<script>console.log(FB.getLoginStatus())</script>` at the end of my body but I always get FB is not defined. Any suggestions?

Comment: Then you likely did not embed and initialize the JS SDK correctly. (Careful, it is a different script than the one the customer chat plugin now uses.)